# In my Tiny msc text edior i want only one text editor

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have implemented a tiny msc in my project . I want one text editor and one text area , But all the text area in my page appears as a text editor , How i avoid this problem , Below is my code ..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",
    editor_selector 
    plugins : "safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager,filemanager",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,

    // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
    content_css : "css/example.css",

    // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
    template_external_list_url : "js/template_list.js",
    external_link_list_url : "js/link_list.js",
    external_image_list_url : "js/image_list.js",
    media_external_list_url : "js/media_list.js",

    // Replace values for the template plugin
    template_replace_values : {
        username : "Some User",
        staffid : "991234"
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `mode : "textareas"`, either use:

1. `mode : "exact"` with the `elements` option to specify a single element.
2. `mode : "none"` and call `tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "id")` directly on the element.

See: http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/mode

Option #1 is the easiest for your situation.  Example from the documentation:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "elm1",
    ...
});

...

<textarea id="elm1" ...
```